# Eigen and c++11 assignment and rreference

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm getting very confused with c++11 move semantics and especially with eigen- does it have an assignment operator for rvalue (operator=(Type&&)), or not?

This code crashes over size mismatch:

```
    Eigen::VectorXd&& func(){
        Eigen::VectorXd&& v=Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(5);
        return std::move(v);
    }

    Eigen::VectorXd v=Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(10);
    v.block(0,0,5,1)=func();
```

The only way it worked was if func was defined as:

```
    Eigen::VectorXd func(){
        Eigen::VectorXd v=Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(5);
        return v;
    }
```

Even the regular single reference (&) didn't work. When can I use these references? What is going on with the memory?
Thanks!

Comment: That's absolutely correct, you should return by value. Unless you want to return a reference to an object that exists regardless of the reference, return by value. References refer to objects. If you can't show the object, there's nothing your reference can refer to. Did I mention already that you should return by value?

Comment: Do not return references to objects with automatic storage duration ("local variables"). Rvalue references don't change that, this has always been forbidden.

Comment: Ok I got that returning by regular reference is a bad idea because the object doesn't exist out of the function. Thanks for that. Of coarse it will work by value- there's not reason it shouldn't, but all this copying!!

Comment: @user2070148 No, that's the thing. The returned object is an rvalue (and `return` statements are required by the standard to try moving first), so returning by value normally triggers moves, not copies.

Comment: The std::move thing makes the object moved and live outside the function, but there's no assignment operator that works with Rvalue-reference probably.. There's a copy constructor though, I think. I tried the first func (with &&), and instead of assigning it to an existing block, assigning it to  Eigen::VectorXd v1 = func();- it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a local variable. It doesn't matter that it is a rvalue reference, the local variable gets destructed when the function returns.

Your version that returns by value is the best, as it will utilize the move constructor automatically (assuming Eigen implemented move constructors).

Comment: std::move should keep the memory of this rvalue. But it can't be assigned to an existing eigen matrix anyway, because it doesn't support operator=(Eigen::VectorXd&&), as far as I checked..

Comment: @user2070148 this is not correct, `std::move()` does not actually *move* anything. You can think of it as tagging a variable to let others know it can be moved/swapped/modified if they want. But in your original example, there's nothing that moves it, so it just gets destructed, and you're left with a dangling reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly the thing that I don't understand- when can I make it actually move the variable? If I use the first version of func() as: Eigen::VectorXd v1=func(); The program doesn't crash.. So the move worked? Because if it's a dangling reference- shouldn't the program crash?

Comment: I checked again, it crashes.. Thanks.